# Getting values from dataGrid1_SelectionChanged using general TABLES not one of a kind

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I am using Silverlight.

I would like to devise a general method, not in which I have to specify the table name!

I want to generalize

```
 ServiceReference1.Customer selected_row = dataGrid1.SelectedItem as ServiceReference1.Customer;

            selected_row = (ServiceReference1.Customer) dataGrid1.SelectedItem;

           label1.Content = selected_row.CustomerID.ToString();
```

I want to get the row clicked on, and traverse it to display it in text boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this in binding like this:

```
       <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="100" Name="DataGrid1" Width="120" />
        <sdk:Label Content="{Binding ElementName=DataGrid1, Path=SelectedItem.CustomerId}"/>
```

If you do not want to do this in xaml then you can just parse the sender of your eventhandler

```
var datagrid = sender as DataGrid;
```